# How to prevent DOM from loading until object is fully loaded into $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, javascript-objects

I am loading a JSON that is almost 19,000 lines...minified to a single line its about 240k.  I am loading it into my app via index.html file as a global var:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cdjson.js"></script>

var _countries = {
   "country": {
      "USA": {
         "currency": {
            "currencyCode":["USD"],
                "currencyName":["United States Dollar"],
                "currencySymbol":["&#36;"]
         },
         "info": { 
               ...
               ...
         },
         "phone" : {
               ...
         },
         "postal" : {
               ...
         }
      },
      "CAN" : {
         ...
      }
   }
}
```

In the the controller its being assigned to a $scope variable `$scope.countries = _countries.country ;`.  However, when the html DOM for that controller loads its trying to access the $scope variable before before the object is fully loaded into the $scope causing JS object errors like `Cannot read property 'country' of undefined`.

How can I prevent the page from rendering until the $scope object is fully loaded?  The $scope country object is being used in a `<select ng-repeat="countries as country">`

Comment: You should define that variable as an empty array before calling the JSON, then using an async service you load the JSON file and show a progress loading instead of your select. When the async service finishes loading set your $scope.countries again and hide the loading indicator.

Comment: That does not look like a JSON file, but a JavaScript file. There is a difference... Include the script in the `<head>` part of your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Have a flag that indicates when the data was fully loaded to the controller.
Something like

```
<select ng-if="countries.length" ng-repeat="countries as country">
```

Comment: Interesting...gonna try this one.

Comment: Make sure you spell length properly

Comment: @GuyYogev - I thought I had this fixed with another resolution but the issue came back.  Tried yours above and that did not work either.

Comment: Have you tried @Rogers Sampaio suggested? There are 2 parts to take care of here. loading the JSON via a network request, and loading the data into the controller (my suggestion handles only the latter). Plus as trincot mentioned above, it looks like you are loading JS not JSON, they're not the same. Add your updated code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your js files should be loaded at the end of your HTML so you dont have this problem. But if that is not an option for you then add this in your controller

```
$scope.countries = []
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    $scope.countries = _countries.country;
});
```

and in your HTML

```
<select ng-if="countries.length" ng-repeat="countries as country">
```